# SQL Server : how not to display subsequent results if they are the same as the previous ones?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a query that will display the result from this table:

| invoice | position |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 1 |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 2 | Cell 3 |
| Cell 1 | Cell 4 |

The desired result is like this:

| invoice | position |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 1 |
|  | Cell 2 |
|  | Cell 4 |
| Cell 2 | Cell 3 |

I'm hoping for some tips

Comment: What is your SQL database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle) ?

Comment: my database - mssql

Comment: Thats normally something you solve in your front end, not your database.

Answer (score 1):

We could try using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function here along with a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY invoice
        ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(position,
                      CHARINDEX(' ', position) + 1,
                      LEN(position)) AS INT)
    ) = 1 THEN invoice END AS invoice
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    invoice,
    CAST(SUBSTRING(position, CHARINDEX(' ', position) + 1, LEN(position)) AS INT);
```